# Can all random effects design matrices accept collinear columns?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, experiment-design, research-design

I am curious about how the random effects design matrix works, within a mixed model.

I know that the columns of a random effects design matrix are allowed to be collinear with each other, but I am curious as to why this is the case.

My question is: Does a random effects design matrix allow collinear columns because (1) it models random effects (i.e. it is something intrinsic to the concept of random effects), or (2) because of the specific choice of model fitting algorithm (e.g. penalized least squares) used to solve for the random effects coefficients?